# Increase table column width proportionally in Html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a code which is made by display: table property. everything is ok and working perfectly. Now I have fallen a problem that table column are not being increased when it has fixed width.

HTML

```
<div class="table-responsive">

                <div class="ni-table table table-striped table-hover ng-scope  table-blank" id="_blankDivGridID1471321637917" ng-show="show">  <div class="ni-table-row" ng-show="show2">   <div class="ni-table-cell p-none" style="width: 10%;">  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div> <div class="ni-table-cell p-none" style="width: 10%;">  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div> <div class="ni-table-cell p-none" style="width: 15%;">  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div> <div class="ni-table-cell p-none" style="width: 10%;">  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div> <div class="ni-table-cell p-none" style="width: 10%;">  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div> <div class="ni-table-cell p-none" style="width: 10%;"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div> <div class="ni-table-cell p-none" style="width: 2%;">  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div>  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div> <div class="ni-table-row" ng-show="show3">   <div class="ni-table-cell p-none" style="width: 10%;">  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div> <div class="ni-table-cell p-none" style="width: 10%;">  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div> <div class="ni-table-cell p-none" style="width: 15%;">  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div> <div class="ni-table-cell p-none" style="width: 10%;">  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div> <div class="ni-table-cell p-none" style="width: 10%;">  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div> <div class="ni-table-cell p-none" style="width: 10%;"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div> <div class="ni-table-cell p-none" style="width: 2%;">  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div>  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div>  </div></div>
```

and css

```
/*----------------------------------------*/
.ni-table {
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed; }

.ni-table-header-group {
  display: table-header-group; }

.ni-table-header, .ni-table-row {
  display: table-row; }

.ni-table-row-group {
  display: table-row-group; }

.ni-table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap; }

.ni-table > .ni-table-header-group > .ni-table-header > .ni-table-cell,
.ni-table > .ni-table-header > .ni-table-cell {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400; }

/*----------------------------------------*/
.ni-table {
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc; }

.ni-table > .ni-table-header-group > .ni-table-header > .ni-table-cell,
.ni-table > .ni-table-header > .ni-table-cell {
  background: #c5c5c5;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-right: 1px solid #f0f0f0; }
  .ni-table > .ni-table-header-group > .ni-table-header > .ni-table-cell:last-child,
  .ni-table > .ni-table-header > .ni-table-cell:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #dcdcdc; }

.ni-table > .ni-table-row-group > .ni-table-row > .ni-table-cell,
.ni-table > .ni-table-row > .ni-table-cell {
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc; }

.ni-table .ni-table {
  background-color: white; }
```

**Desired output**: table and table column will fit to screen.

Comment: maybe put a `<table>` element with a class of table inside your div `table-responsive`.

Comment: Table and display table are same. no problem do u have any solution for this code?